Does the lore say whether Glass Walkers and drones ever collaborate?
As the question sounds, of the tribes the Glass Walkers have an unconventional relationship with the Weaver - so I wondered if it is mentioned in the lore if they have the usual default attitude to its minions since they are still Garou and ultimately not fallen to the weaver, or if they and the drones ever are willing/able to collaborate against a “common goal” like something Wyrm?
The question is tagged 20th anniversary but if an earlier one mentions something instead, I would definitely be happy to read that too!

Some Try!
There's one attempt at this, and it is detailed in The Book of the Weaver1:

 From the confines of a spartan chamber atop a thirty story glass-and-steel tower overlooking Tokyo’s historic Kashu Highway, Yoyogi Park, and Imperial Palace, a council of eleven spearheads the clash between East and West that has become the Information Age.[...] How is it possible, then, that Chinese and Japanese executives commingle at the uppermost tiers of management? That two of the firm’s eleven directors are female? Or that these directors collectively absent themselves from business once monthly on the eve of the full moon?The truth is at once obvious and appalling. Shinzui is, as its trappings might suggest, the product of a supernatural alliance between business-minded Garou and their influential Kinfolk counterparts; it is this paranormal edge that serves as both lifeboat and liability to the syndicate. [...]

But that attempt does not play out as one might think, as Drones are not even mentioned there. In that first depiction, it's just a very Weaver group, that manages to bring Garou from otherwise warring groups together and break business stereotypes...
Weaver Ascendant!
What really happens in the background is answered as part of the Time of Judgment: Apocalypse book.2

 Shinzui Industries is a Drone controlled Company. The company is instrumental in destroying the way of life of the western Garou - but it also is fighting Pentex for shares, and does lots of hostile takeovers. One by one, Shinzui took over company assets of Pentex, bringing the Wyrm under control... but at the same time, the upper echelons put their eyes to destroy the western Garou, which they see as agents of chaos. Yes, the literal goal of the company starting at anything above middle management is to either turn the Garou into weaver-drones or kill them. Nobody is to be spared...
 And the first pawn on Shinzui's board against the Garou: They destroyed a Caern, annihilated the last Boli Zouhisze and enslaved Emperor Raiden, a wever-drone Garou that ratted his former sept out. The next strikes went on to destroy the Beast Courts they could find, before targeting the Glasswalkers on a global level... by using ex-Pentex assets, esp. Fomori... It's carnage.

To summarize: Even if the Glasswalkers believe they might have fun and good dealings with Drones, the Drones have ulterior motives. They do not fight for the same goals, and to the Drones, Wyrmspawn is a thing they can weaponize for their goals. The goal of the Drones is utterly incompatible with that of the Garou:

The Garou want Gaia to live freely, and Wyrm needs to be halted for that.
The Drones want a world where everyone and everything is perfectly organized and undergoes Clarification to be turned into a Drone. Wyrm is to be enslaved, Wild destroyed. Only Weaver shall be.

While some Garou might genuinely believe in "working together" with drones at first, that's not what happens. It's better to say that this is the convenient entry drug before they fall under the sway of the Drone. In the case of above corporation: Garou started it and secretly used the company to undermine and exploit a leadership position. But as time went on, the real power that undermined the company and the Garou in it became the Drones they had invited at some point as a powerplay against Pentex.

 The only good thing that will arise from this joint venture? The Wyrm will not win. Instead, the Weaver will fixate the world.



The Book of the Weaver, Clarkston (1998), p.87-88.
Apocalypse - Time of Judgement, Stone Mountain (2004), p.116-143.

